# pipe does not write to file

Tags: pipe

I want to get only the number of ms from a ping command to a file
Without piping to a file it works as intended. I'm a little bit lost on why > to a file does not write anything.

This works:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 |egrep --line-buffered -v 'PING|timeout' |sed -l -e 's/^.* time=\(.*\) ms$/\1/g'
```

This does not write anything to ping.dat

```
ping 192.168.1.1 |egrep --line-buffered -v 'PING|timeout' |sed -l -e 's/^.* time=\(.*\) ms$/\1/g' > ping.dat
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Each `|` is potentially surrounded by an stdio output buffer and an stdin input buffer. You need to find out which of those you need to turn off to get realtime piping.

This works for me:

```
ping localhost |egrep --line-buffered -v 'PING|timeout' |\
stdbuf -o0 sed -l -e 's/^.* time=\(.*\) ms$/\1/g' > file
```

Initially I had put `stdbuf -i0 -o0` before every command and then found out which were unnecessary.

Comment: Doesn't the `--line-buffered` with egrep solve this? Or does grep's output then also get buffered?

Comment: @Otheus Since `stdbuf -o0` does solve the problem, it appears `sed` uses stdio and the stream gets stuck in its `stdout`'s output buffer.

Comment: Oh I see! OK, I confirmed GNU sed's `-u` also does this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU, then it appears the `-l` option to sed is incorrect: you probably want the `-u` (unbuffered) option. Also, the `grep` is superfluous. You should be able to get what you want from just the sed:

```
ping $HOST | sed -u -n '/ ms$/s/.* time=\(.*\) ms$/\1/p' >file.out
```

The `-n` suppresses normal matching output, while the `s///p` forces the output of matching lines.